# Obtener una imagen por default en dashboard PHP Ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

Buen día colegas, quiero obtener una imagen por default en una tabla del dashboard, estoy metiendo un if para que me traiga la de default en caso de que no haya imagen dentro de mi ajax.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     async: false,
     url: "<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>alumno/readByIdEscuela",
     dataType: 'json', 
     success: function(data) {
        
        $.each(data, function(ind, elem) {
           if (ind <= 4) {
              var img = new Image();
              if (elem.foto_alumno == null || elem.foto_alumno == '') {
              }else{
                    var img = '<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/img/default.jpg'
                 }
              
              var htmlTags = '<tr>' +
                 '<td><img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" style="max-width: 60px; max-height: 60px" src="<?php echo constant('URL') ?>public/alumno/' 
                 + elem.appaterno_alumno + '_' + elem.apmaterno_alumno + '_' 
                 + elem.nombre_alumno + '/' + elem.foto_alumno + '"</img><td>' +
                 '<td>' + elem.nombre_alumno + '<td>' +
                 '<td>' + elem.email_alumno + '<td>' +
                 '</tr>';
              $('#tableAlumnos').append(htmlTags);
```

Esta parte sería del sistema donde quiero que se muestre la de default.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Pensando en que `elem.foto_alumno` trae un dato como *nombreunicoimagen.jpg* o null, se pudiera hacer algo como:

```
const BASE_URL = <?php echo constant('URL'); ?>; 
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     async: false,
     url: BASE_URL + "alumno/readByIdEscuela",
     dataType: 'json', 
     success: function(data) {
        
        $.each(data, function(ind, elem) {
           if (ind <= 4) {                           
              let src_foto_alumno = (elem.foto_alumno !== null)? BASE_URL + 'public/img/default.jpg':BASE_URL + 'public/alumno/'+elem.foto_alumno;
              
              var htmlTags = '<tr>' +
                 '<td><img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" style="max-width: 60px; max-height: 60px" src="'+src_foto_alumno+'"' 
                 + elem.appaterno_alumno + '_' + elem.apmaterno_alumno + '_' 
                 + elem.nombre_alumno + '/' + elem.foto_alumno + '"</img><td>' +
                 '<td>' + elem.nombre_alumno + '<td>' +
                 '<td>' + elem.email_alumno + '<td>' +
                 '</tr>';
              $('#tableAlumnos').append(htmlTags);
```